# How I post on facebook page without clicking button in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app was posting on facebook without user interaction in the last 2-3 days, but now, and I don't why, this is not working.

Here's my code:

```
function post_fb($fb_text) {

    echo file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token="."***".$fb_text);

    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array('message' => $fb_text, 'access_token' => "***");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $tuData = curl_exec($ch);
    if(!curl_errno($ch)){
      return true;
      /*$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      print_r($info);
      echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];*/
    } 
    /*else {
      echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $tuData;*/ 

}
```

Comment: can you give us some code to work with please

Comment: put the code you have tried.please

Comment: This is code which am trying in this am not know how i generate access token every time